# Is the syntax for local port forwarding wrong on Zsh?

Tags: ssh, terminal, port, zsh

I am trying to set up a function on my `.zshrc` file to create an easy way to do local port forwarding. My goal is starting a Jupyter server on my university's cluster and then using local port forwarding to access it. I have the following on my `.zshrc` file:

```
function jptt(){
    # Forwards port $1 into port $2 and listens to it
    ssh -N -f -L $1:localhost:$2 rgr6291@klc0201.ci.northwestern.edu
}
```

However, whenever I try to use it, for example with `jptt 8888 8888`, I get the following error:

`Bad local forwarding specification '8888ocalhost:8888'`

Am I handling strings or arguments in a wrong way? I can't understand why it isn't able to execute the command. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, you can add history-style expansion operators to the end of a variable expansion. `$1:localhost` is treated as the expansion `$1:l`, followed by the text `localhost`. To prevent this interpretation, use explicit braces to delimit the parameter expansion.

```
ssh -N -f -L ${1}:localhost:$2 rgr6291@klc0201.ci.northwestern.edu
```

You can also quote the parameter expansion to separate the `:` from the expansion syntactically:

```
ssh -N -f -L "$1":localhost:$2 rgr6291@klc0201.ci.northwestern.edu
```

---

`:l`, by the way, causes the expansion to be converted to lowercase. For example,

```
% x=FOO
% echo $x
FOO
% echo $x:l
foo
```

With braces, the operator would go *inside* the braces, immediately after the parameter name.

```
% echo ${x}:l
FOO:l
% echo ${x:l}
foo
```